# How prove this inequality $3013*\frac{3}{4}>\sqrt{9082.321}$

Tags: inequality

How prove this inequality
$$3013*\frac{3}{4}>\sqrt{9082.321}$$

Comment: can you not just square both sides?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero after having multiplied both sides by 4...

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes even faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that obviously
$$
\sqrt{9082.321} < \sqrt{10000} = 100 < 1000 < \frac{3013 \cdot 3}{4}
$$
so no squaring is needed.